# Overload Arithmetic operator from an abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, c++17

I would like to use polymorphous of c++ overloads for the following :

I have a class `DataTypes` This class will contain a pointer to an abstract class called `base`.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual base& operator+(const base &obj) = 0;
};

class derive: public base
{
public:
    virtual derive& operator+(const base &obj)
    {
        cout << "overloading base" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual derive& operator+(const derive &obj)
    {
        cout << "derive + derive" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

There will be many derive classes and I would like to write the following:

```
    base* b1 = new derive();
    base* b2 = new derive();
    *b1+*b1;
```

This will return the print `overloading base`

if I do this, I get what I'm looking for:

```
    *(dynamic_cast<derive*>(b1))+*(dynamic_cast<derive*>(b2));
OR
    *(static_cast<derive>(b1))+*(static_cast<derive*>(b2));
```

This will result with the required print `derive + derive`

My question is how do I perform this without casting?
Or if there is casting required, how can it be dynamic?
because the dynamic cast is not really dynamic unless it is something like:

```
    *(dynamic_cast<typeof(b1)>(b1))+*(dynamic_cast<derive*>(b2));
```

But this doesn't work.

Edit:
To be clear, a member class of the class `DataTypes` will be an abstract class called `base`, but the access to it will as mentioned something like `b1+b2`. Where `b1,b2` are from the `derive` class

Comment: Perhaps you should use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) here, to declare the `operator+` function with the actual arguments of the derived class instead.

Comment: This is definitely something I'm looking into at the moment now. However, it will break the original idea that I hold an abstract pointer of a class and by its implementation, it will call the right function. In this idea I won't be able to have a member ```base * data``` in the ```DataType``` class.

Comment: Look up "multiple dispatch". There are solutions, but nothing great.

Comment: You could move the `dynamic_cast` into `derive::operator+(const base &obj)`. As in `if (auto d = dynamic_cast<const dervie*>(&obj)) { /* derive + derive */ } else { /* derive + something else */ }` . In the calling code, `*b1+*b2` would work as is.